# CakePHP find hasMany associated model

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I got a `Item` model that `belongsTo` a `Category`, ergo `Category` `hasMany` `Item`.

from the `CategoriesController` I want to fetch all the `Item` the category has.

I tried this, but it isn't working:

```
if($id == null) {
    throw new NotFoundException(__('404'));
}

$this->Category->id = $id;
if(!$this->Category->exists()) {
    throw new NotFoundException(__('404'));
}

$items = $this->Category->Item->find();
$this->set('items',$items);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your models are setup correctly with corresponding `$hasMany` and `$belongsTo`, getting the category is enough by default:

```
$category = $this->Category->findById($id);
```

The Items will be automatically included in the `$category` array. You can check it with the `debug()` function:

```
debug($category);
```

Please also note that you can filter exactly what linked models you want to retrieve when you do a `find()` by using the very useful [Containable](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html) behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a fan of `recursive > -1` so I propose another way.

```
$items = $this->Category->find('all', array('contain'=>'Item',
                                                  'recursive'=>-1));
$this->set('items',$items);
```

or the simplest

```
$items = $this->Category->Item->find('all', 
                                     array('conditions'=>array('category_id'=>$id)));
```

Your problem was not to specify "all" and not giving conditions to fill.